# Using strstr() to exclude two values

Tags: php, strstr

I have this code:

```
if(!strstr($value, '<p>')){...}
```

This outputs data from a database to an excel file excluding any fields that contain `<p>`.

I would also like to exclude fields that contains `</script>`

Ive tried these two code snippets without success:

```
if((!strstr($value, '<p>')) and (!strstr($value, '</script>')))
```

And:

```
if(!strstr($value, '<p>', '</script>'))
```

Basically my question is how can I exclude both `<p>` and `</scrpit>` from my excel file?

Comment: Your logic seems to be working correctly. See http://codepad.org/MnQ6z0Ez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regural expression and preg_match function for this one:

```
if(!preg_match("/(<p>|<\/script>)/", $value)) {
    // Do your magic!   
}
```

You can read more about preg_match here: [PHP preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
And if you have problems with regular expressions, check out this example: [example](http://rubular.com/r/OZ8pNqbme5) and play around with it to get a hold of regular expressions.

And as far as I can see, your logic should work just fine. Maybe your $value variables hold wrong data. Anyway, you have something to get you going.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Some people, when faced with a problem think, "I know I'll use Regular Expressions!".  Now they have two problems.

Comment: I don't see or have any problems with regular expressions :)

Comment: Other than being, you know, slow?  And difficult for novices to understand and maintain?  It's nice that you provided it, you might also want to explain it.

Comment: Since op's code sample is valid as far as I can tell, your "solution" (which is just a different way of doing the same thing) *will fail as well* because it's isn't logically different that what op already tried.

Comment: This works great, thanks. To shorten my code I went with if(!strstr($value, '<')){...} to take out any fields that contained a '<'...maybe a hack, but hey it works

Comment: If want to keep the column empty, instead of shift the rest of the values up in my excel file how would I do that? for instance if that value is not read into excel, all the values below that value shift up in excel. I just want it to skip that column/row and go on to the next

Answer (score 0):

this works.

```
<?php

$a = array('ok0', 'somthing <p>','2222 </script>', 'ok1');
foreach ($a as $value)
    if((!strstr($value, '<p>')) && (!strstr($value, '</script>')))
        echo $value;
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest using `strpos` instead, but this should work fine:

```
if(!strstr($value, '<p>') and !strstr($value, '</script>')){
    // Write your file
}
```

...if it doesn't, something else is going on.  Your `$value` may not be what you expect, for example.

**EDIT** Replaced `&&` with `and` per op's code example

Comment: `&&` and `and` are functional equivalent in PHP, except for slightly different precedence levels. all you've done is rearrange deckchairs on the titanic.

Comment: @MarcB Op gave **two** approaches.  I'm simply saying, THAT ONE should work.  I wasn't implying it would work because I used `&&`, I did that out of habit.  I will fix it to appease the SO police.

Comment: sorry, but there's far too many trivial rearrangings of code that do nothing, but still get put up as answers. e.g. op has `$x = "hello $there"` and someone's "obvious" solution is that `$x = "hello " . $there` will magically fix the problem.

Comment: Did you read my answer in its entirety?  To paraphrase: "what you have should work, if it doesn't something else is wrong, like your $value might not be what you expect".  How is that irrelevant?  Point was to put to rest that it was an issue with his code, and suggest he look elsewhere for a culprit.  And FWIW I agree w/ you on trival code tweaks that are functionally equivalent. That was not my intention here although it clearly reads that way to you.